# Invoke command OnSelectionChanged in GridViewComboBoxColumn WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid

Is there any way that i can invoke a `command` and pass the `SelectedItem` as parameter to `ViewModel` when the selection change occurs?

XAML:

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValueMemberPath="StatusName" DisplayMemberPath="StatusName" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Shipped, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsVisible="{Binding IsExist, Mode=TwoWay}">
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

I tried like adding `Interation Triggers` but i couldn't able to find the exact event to pass the `SelectedItem` as parameter,

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ContextMenuClosing">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding StatusDropdownCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel:

```
public ICommand StatusDropdownCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(StatusDropdown); } }

void StatusDropdown()
{

}
```

Kindly help.

**Updated Code:**

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValueMemberPath="StatusName" DisplayMemberPath="StatusName" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Shipped, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsVisible="{Binding IsExist, Mode=TwoWay}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Converter:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selector.SelectionChanged" >
<Converter:CustomCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
</Converter:RoutedEventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

Issue Occured:

[image: Issue]

Comment: read [this](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/01/18/invokecommandaction-with-eventargs-as-command-parameter/) article

Comment: @Alekstim: There is no event for ComboBoxColumn as like that and that's why the question is raised. If you are sure, then you can post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that subscription to Selector.SelectionChanged routed event should do the job.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <local:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selector.SelectionChanged">
            <local:CustomCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
        </local:RoutedEventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

You need custom trigger to handle attached events:

```
public class RoutedEventTrigger : EventTriggerBase<DependencyObject>
{
    RoutedEvent _routedEvent;

    public RoutedEvent RoutedEvent
    {
        get { return _routedEvent; }
        set { _routedEvent = value; }
    }

    public RoutedEventTrigger()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        Behavior behavior = base.AssociatedObject as Behavior;
        FrameworkElement associatedElement = base.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;

        if (behavior != null)
        {
            associatedElement = ((IAttachedObject)behavior).AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        }
        if (associatedElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Routed Event trigger can only be associated to framework elements");
        }
        if (RoutedEvent != null)
        {
            associatedElement.AddHandler(RoutedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnRoutedEvent));
        }
    }
    void OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnEvent(args);
    }
    protected override string GetEventName()
    {
        return RoutedEvent.Name;
    }
}
```

Also you may use your own action for triggering your command:

```
public sealed class CustomCommandAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(CustomCommandAction), null);

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            ICommand command = this.Command;
            if (command != null)
            {
                if (this.CommandParameter != null)
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (command.CanExecute(parameter))
                    {
                        command.Execute(parameter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this exception on execute: `Routed Event trigger can only be associated to framework elements`. On the line `if (RoutedEvent != null)`

Comment: This means that your AssociatedObject is null. Where do you put your i:Interaction.Triggers section? Please try o put inside your grid, something like <telerik:RadGridView> .. <i:Interaction.Triggers> .. </i:Interaction.Triggers> ..

Comment: Yes, it is inside the grid within the column. Also the exception is thrown before i can see the UI.

Comment: Try to put it inside GridView itself. As you can see in RoutedEventTrigger.OnAttached method associatedElement  defines like this: FrameworkElement associatedElement = base.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement; So if the column is not a FrameworkElement, you will get null. Also, try to put breakpoint to that line to find out what's going on.

Comment: Tried many ways still the same issue. The behaviour is also null. Any idea?

Comment: What is the type of base.AssociatedObject in OnAttached() method then breakpoint is triggered?

Comment: If you'll put your triggers section right beneath the root element of the grid <telerik:RadGridView><i:Interaction.Triggers>... AssociatedObject will be of grid type, which is inherited from FrameworkElement, and your associatedElement will not be null.

Comment: Yes, that works fine. But it works for all dropdown columns in the grid. I want it to work only for the specified columns. How can i do that?

Comment: In your SelectionChangedCommand execute action OnSelectionChanged(object args) you'll recieve args parameter, that should of type SelectionChangedEventArgs. You can find if event was raised by specified combobox by properties of that args object. Just put breakpoint in that handler and take a look what properties are different for different columns.

Comment: Yes, but I just want that event to be raised only for that specified ComboBoxColumn. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess not, because that even is triggered for the whole grid and not for a specific column. From my perspective the best place for filtering is in command execute based on args properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer.